# List of all the SItes in Azure tenant

Tags: azure, powershell

like to know all the sites in Azure that are currently associated to our Azure Tenant includes full URL,azure web apps,azure SQL,Storage accounts,Datalake,Cosmosdb,container registries
Tried Get-AzureADTenantDetail and also az resource list but not able find it

Any Powershell script will help

Comment: SO is not a scriptwriting service, own effort is required to get help. Please post a sample of your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**Azure CLI**

```
az resource list
```

**Powershell**

```
Get-AzureRmResource
```

Comment: Trying make it has powershell script i need details like webapps,azure SQL etc.,

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: in selected tenant powershell script has to execute and find all the list has azure web apps,azure SQL,Storage accounts,Datalake,Cosmosdb,container registries

Comment: Get-AzResource -ODataQuery "ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' or ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.Sql/servers'or ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.Web/sites'or ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries'or ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts'" | ft 
Get-AzWebApp | foreach-object {$_} | select-object DefaultHostName, ResourceGroup | ft >> D:\one.txt
Trying to Merge the output in single line

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Get-AzureRmResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermresource?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to get the list of resources in an Azure Subscription. By default this Cmdlet will list all resources in an Azure Subscription. To get a list of certain resource types, you can specify an `OData` filter query.

For example, the Cmdlet below will list all storage accounts and webapps in an Azure Subscription:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ODataQuery "ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' or ResourceType eq 'Microsoft.Web/sites'" | ft
```

You will need to find the proper resource type values for each kind of resource that you want to find.

Another thing to notice is that this Cmdlet is scoped to a single Azure Subscription. If your Azure Tenant serves as authentication/authorization source for multiple subscriptions, you would need to run this Cmdlet for each subscription separately.

Comment: Ok i will do..can you help me with the query for azure SQL and DataLake

Comment: Please try it out yourself first :) and ask questions if you’re stuck somewhere.

Comment: Sure i am trying

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple tenants, you can switch between tenants and get resources within them (subscription by subscription) via

connect-azaccount -Tenant [different tenant id]

$context = Get-AzSubscription [subscriptionid in different tenant id]
set-azcontext $context

get-azresource > resources.tenantname.subcription.txt 
where tenantname and subscription are the names of the tenant and subscription in english form (instead of id's).

you should probably not use those azurerm commands anymore, they will stop working sometime in 2024.  use the az equivalents (basically replace azurerm with az (yeah, i could delete urerm but that seems weirder!))